# Django lte & gte failing When Checking For Dates Range

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to check the calendar for dates already booked so a user won't be able to book a room if it has been booked already. I used the lte and gte to check for dates and I'm not happy with the result so far.

Models:

```
class HotelCalendar(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    hotelrooms=models.ForeignKey(HotelRooms)
    checkin_booked_date=models.DateField(max_length=20, help_text='yy-mm-dd e.g. 2014-02-01')
    checkout_booked_date=models.DateField(max_length=20, help_text='yy-mm-dd e.g. 2014-02-01')
```

For the hotelroom with id 1, dates in the calendar are,

```
checkedin_booked_date= 2016-06-01   
checkedout_booked_date 2016-06-14
```

You can also check the attached file to see how my DB looks like.
[image]

**The Problem**

In my db shell, I ran the below code and I'm getting 'dates available' instead of 'booked already', because the date is still within the range.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date= datetime.date(2016, 6, 1)
>>> end_date= datetime.date(2016, 6, 5)
>>> check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date), Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> if check_for_bookings:
...     print 'booked already'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
   available
>>>
```

Any idea of what am missing?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the solution below but it failed to confirm that the dates within June 2 and June 13 have been booked for hotelroom id 1. It's returning available instead of not available.

```
>>> start_date='2016-06-02'
>>> end_date='2016-06-13'
>>> check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date) | Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> if check_for_bookings:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
 ...     print 'available'
 ...
 available
 >>>
```

Another thing is after I changed the end and start date and run the query, it worked. It showed that the room is not available.

```
>>> start_date='2016-06-03'
>>> end_date='2016-06-14'
>>> check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date)|Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> if check_for_bookings:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
not available
```

Could this be a bug?

Comment: Don't you need logical or logic, ie `Q(...)|Q(...)`?

Comment: from the django docs to [Q-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):
if a Q object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments.

Comment: yet to get concrete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date), Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
```

to

```
check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date) | Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
```

**Update:** 
Check the query above this update, I have replaced `&` with `|`, the logic being as follows.

A user, tries to look for availability, he enters his desired date lets say(as per your example) `2016/06/01 to 2016/06/05` so you have to look up all the bookings starting from `2016/06/01` along with bookings upto `2016/06/05`. So, making use of `Q` and `|` operator you will able to find out the availability starting from the checkin date to checkout date.

Comment: @Yoyo can you share some sample data from your db?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. check it out.

Comment: @Yoyo instead of using `&` use `|` operator. I have updated the answer, check it out

Comment: kindly check the problem above for your solution I tried and what I got.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date range

```
start_date = "2011-01-01"
final_date = "2011-01-31"
check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(checkin_booked_date__range=[start_date, final_date], hotelrooms_id=1)
```

date can also be a date object or string in above format

Comment: @YoYo you will get objects between "2011-01-01"  to  "2011-01-30". If you are using DateField it will certainly work.